# A problem in measure theory (outer measure)

Tags: measure-theory

Show that for every set $A = P(\mathbb{R})$ (power set) there exists $B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (Borel set) s.t $A \subset B$ $\lambda^{*}(A) = \lambda (B)$ and $\lambda (N) = 0 \ \forall N \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $N = \mathbb{B} \backslash A$
where

$$
\lambda^{*}(A) = \inf \{ \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda (I_j) | I_j \in J, j \in \mathbb{N}, A \subset \cup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} I_j \} 
$$

where $J$ is the half open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}$ i.e $[a,b)$

If I start looking at the case when $\lambda^{*} (A) < \infty$. By definition of $\inf$ $\exists \epsilon >0$ s.t for $S \subset \cup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} I_j$ then $\lambda (S) - \lambda^{*} (A) < \epsilon$. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\lambda^{\ast}(A)<\infty$, for each $n\in{\bf{N}}$, we find some open set $G_{n}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{j=1}I_{j}^{n}\supseteq A$ such that $\lambda^{\ast}(A)+\dfrac{1}{n}>\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lambda\left(I_{j}^{n}\right)\geq\lambda^{\ast}(A)$. By letting that $G=\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}G_{n}\supseteq A$, $G$ is Borel such that $\lambda^{\ast}(A)\leq\lambda^{\ast}(G)\leq\lambda^{\ast}(G_{n})=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lambda\left(I_{j}^{n}\right)<\lambda^{\ast}(A)+\dfrac{1}{n}$, $n=1,2,...$ Taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ we have $\lambda^{\ast}(G)=\lambda^{\ast}(A)$, done.

Comment: Can you explain the first line "assuming that..." a Little deeper, it seems that I have just forgot something elementary which I can not figure out.

Comment: Isn't that what you have assumed for yourself? Indeed, you need to do this problem separately by the cases that $\lambda^{\ast}(A)<\infty$ and $\lambda^{\ast}(A)=\infty$.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It is the "For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we find some open set $G_n = \cup I_{j}^{n}$ ..."

Comment: Okay, I have posted the comment over there, It means that for each stage $n$, the $B$ that you find is not necessarily the same as the $B$ that you have found in other $n′$, so we need to write the subscript nn instead of just B

Comment: So, those $I_{j}$ are not necessarily the same with the $I_{j}$ chosen according to the other $G_{n}$, that's why we have the superscript $I_{j}^{n}$ instead. Indeed, you can write $I_{j,n}$ with $n$ as the subscript instead of superscript.

Comment: Ok once again, I'm explaning bad. Let me try again. We have that $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ lets say $A = (a,b)$ then you could choose $(a, a/2) = I_1, \ \ (a/2, b) = I_2$. Then $G = I_1 \cup I_2$. Why do we need more than one $G$ i,e $G_n$?

Comment: The point is, you do not know what exactly $A$ is, of course if $A=(a,b)$, even choosing $G=(a,b)$ will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49328/discussion-between-olba12-and-user284331).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.

For $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists $\displaystyle B_n =\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N} I_{j,n}$ with $I_{j,n} \in J$ such that

$$\lambda(B_n)-\lambda^*(A)\le \frac{1}{n}$$ Then define
$$\displaystyle B=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n$$

Comment: I seem to miss something, what does the notation of $n$ in $B_n$ mean? I Think I have missed some definition of notation or something. But the $j$ in $I$ stands for the j:th rectangular set, but what does the $n$ mean?

Comment: It means that for each stage $n$, the $B$ that you find is not necessarily the same as the $B$ that you have found in other $n'$, so we need to write the subscript $n$ instead of just $B$.